# Rewrite htaccess to nginx with http authorization

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have a apache2 rewrite rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^down.pl down.pl [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:AUTHORIZATION},L,QSA]
```

Please, how to rewrite it for nginx?

My nginx code looks like:

```
setenv HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:$http_authorization;
rewrite ^/down.pl /down.pl last;
```

But it doesn't work, I cannot start nginx server at all due error.

Config:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.example.tld example.tld;
    root /srv/!example.tld/!www;

    index  desktop.pl index.html index.htm core.tom core.pl;

    location / {     
        setenv HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:$http_authorization;
        rewrite ^/down.pl /down.pl last;
    }

    location ~ \.pl|cgi|tom$ {
        gzip off;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.pl;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/!example.tld/!www$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to give more details, complete nginx config, how are you passing the request back to perl? There is no direct translation of this. You need to use `fastcgi_param` to pass the values

Comment: Ah, thanks I added it.

Comment: Remove the `location /` block and Try adding `fastcgi_param HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization;` to the fastcgi_pass block

Comment: and where to put rewrite ^/down.pl /down.pl last;?

Comment: Not needed in this case